# I enter 0 but ExtJS saves null to DB

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When I enter 0 into my ExtJS input field (ie. numberfield) When I save the form I get null on the way to the DB. I there any special setting I need to enable in order for 0 to treated like 0 and not like null?

Here's my field's code:

```
{
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        itemId: 'testField',
                        id: 'testField',
                        fieldLabel: "testField",
                        fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                        labelWidth: 320,
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        decimalPrecision: Ext.util.Format.currencyPrecision,
                        allowBlank: true,
                        allowDecimals: true,
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 999.9999,
                        defaultValue: null,
                        allowNull: true,
                        hideTrigger: true,
                        keyNavEnabled: false,
                        mouseWheelEnabled: false
                    },
```

Comment: Where is the name of your field ? And open the chrome web console to see the data sent to the server, and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you forgot to give the field a name. A look into the submission would have shown that the form data submitted by `form.submit()` is

```
testField-inputEl:0
```

I don't think you chose that name in your backend object, or did you?

I furthermore think that your backend, whichever you chose, decided that a value that has not been submitted should be defined as null. But all this is purely speculative, since you gave no details, only a few lines of view definition.

For further questions, please keep in mind to inspect and aggregate for us the whole stack:

- Front-end form definition
- Submission code
- Transmitted data
- Back-end code
- Back-end object content
- Generated database queries
- Resulting database records